# Wrong time on RODC after dcpromo

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vmware-esxi, time-synchronization, rodc

My team has been experiencing this strange problem: After doing dcpromo (followed by reboot), the time on the newly promoted RODC rolls back to the year 2011.

Before dcpromo, the time is correct.

The time on the head office's DCs are all correct (and synchronized to an NTP server, which itself synchronized with [0-3].id.pool.ntp.org).

What could possibly be the cause?

More info:

- RODC is Windows Server 2008 R2
- The server was deployed from a sysprep-ed image
- Server is a VM, running on VMware ESXi 5

Should you need even more info, I'll provide it here.

Comment: What's the time on your ESXi host?  Is the new RDOC perhaps synchronizing time from that source for some reason?

Comment: Hmm, makes sense... let me verify with my team. The server is located on a satellite office, so I don't have direct access to it.

Comment: I have seen this before with vmtools set to update to the hosts time.  We normally disable this kind of syncing and rely on pointing the PDC to an NTP and relying on ADs own domain hierarchy to sort the time out.